# Как передать через сигнал в поток PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, сигналы-слоты

Как, то что я ввёл в `QLineEdit`, передать через сигнал в поток `QThread`?

Например я в `QLineEdit` ввёл текст "Hello world", а он уже вывелся через метод `run` в потоке? Из потока как передать сигналы я понимаю, а как в поток передать нет.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(644, 387)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 110, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 50, 50, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 220, 75, 43))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        # через этот метод вывести
        for i in range(1, 10):
            self.sleep(1)
            self.mysignal.emit("i = %s" % i)


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)

    def func1(self):
        self.thread = MyThread()
        self.thread.start()
        self.thread.mysignal.connect(self.on_change, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)

    def on_change(self, s):
        self.label.setText(s)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передать значения методам класса можно через  Метод `__init__`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(644, 387)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 110, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 50, 50, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 220, 75, 43))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, text):                                              # + , text
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        self.text = text                                                   # +

    def run(self):
        # через этот метод вывести
        for i in range(1, 10):
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(1000)                                    #  self.sleep(1)
            self.mysignal.emit("i = {} <-> {}".format(i, self.text))       # ("i = %s" % i)


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)

    def func1(self):
        self.text = self.lineEdit.text()                                      # +++
        self.thread = MyThread(self.text)                                     # +++ self.text
        self.thread.mysignal.connect(self.on_change, type=QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.thread.start()
#        self.thread.mysignal.connect(self.on_change, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)

    def on_change(self, s):
        self.label.setText(s)
        self.label.adjustSize()                                                # +++ 

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(644, 387)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 110, 500, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 50, 50, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 220, 150, 43))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self ):                                             
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        self.text = "__init__"                                                # +++                                            

    def run(self):
        for i in range(1, 40):           # Какой-то цикл
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(1000)                                    
            self.mysignal.emit("Поток работает: i = {} <-> {}".format(i, self.text))       
        self.finished.emit()

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.setText("Запустить поток")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Напишите здесь текст и нахмите "
                                         "`Enter` для передачи текста в поток.")
        self.lineEdit.setToolTip("press RETURN to send")
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("""
            QLineEdit {
               border: None;
               font-size: 14px;
               }
               """)
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.sendText)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def func1(self):
        self.thread = MyThread() 
        self.thread.mysignal.connect(self.on_change, type=QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
        self.thread.start()

    def on_change(self, s):
        self.label.setText(s)
        self.label.adjustSize()    

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def sendText(self):
        self.thread.text = self.lineEdit.text()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_finished(self):
        s = self.label.text().replace("Поток работает", "Поток завершил работу")
        self.label.setText(s)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это я знаю как делать,просто интересно можно ли передать через сигнал в поток.

Comment: @sens250 Возможно практический все, но я видимо плохо понимаю, что надо сделать. Я добавил еще один пример - пробуйте.

Answer (score -1):

В вопросе представлено мало информации, но, чтобы передать сигнал в поток (если вопрос в этом), необходимо использовать в потоке `QEventLoop::exec()` в том месте потока, где необходимо обработать пришедший сигнал.

Вторым вариантом, в котором я менее уверен, может быть добавление `Qt::DirectConnection` или `Qt::QueuedConnection` пятым параметром в метод `connect`.

Comment: Добавил простой код.

Comment: @sens250 Кто ловит сигнал `mysignal`?

Comment: через self.mysignal.emit("i = %s" % i) и mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str) я передаю на вывод в lineEdit.Это лишнее,могу удалить.Как передавать из потока я знаю,а как в поток нет.

Comment: @sens250 Где в Вашем коде участок, обрабатывающий посланный сигнал `mysignal`? Как `lineEdit` его получает?

Comment: Ошибся,получает label.Код дополнил.Выводит из потока.

Comment: @sens250 Если вы получаете сигнал из потока, а не передаёте его в поток, на первый взгляд всё должно работать. Либо я чего-то не понимаю, либо Ваш код передаёт сигнал ИЗ потока, а не В него.

Comment: @sens250 Чтобы передать сигнал В поток, необходимо соединить этот сигнал со слотом, находящимся в потоке, и добавить `QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection`. Или же в нужном месте в потоке вызвать что-то наподобие `QEventLoop.exec()` (у меня сейчас нет python под рукой, потому не могу написать точное название метода)